# Is Kale stronger than a super saiyan blue in the anime?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

So in the last edition of the Dragon Ball Super manga (I believe it was #38)

> Kale was able to defeat Anilaza, which in the anime it took 2 super saiyan blue, Freezer, 17, and Gohan to defeat

I know that it's said what happens in the Dragon Ball Super manga doesnt count for the Dragon Ball Super anime, but in the other hand, we see ideas created by Toyotaro in the manga being incorporated in the anime (like the Super Saiyan God/Super Saiyan Blue switch technique and probably Vegeta turning into super saiyan god, considering the artwork we have seen released along the movie trailer, another idea made by Toyotaro)

Besides, we also saw Kale taking on a super saiyan blue kamehameha from Goku, but it looked to me that fans were in denial and argued Goku didnt use his full super saiyan blue power, when nothing could guarantee that not using his full power could also have meaning not using super saiyan blue kaioken x20, since that's Goku full power. More hints in the anime seems to point in the same direction, Vegeta saying Kale is a monster (what would he say that if she werent stronger than a super saiyan blue), Jiren taking her as a battle when he didnt bother to fight the super saiyan blue Goku and Vegeta, and so on. (Probaly more hints I dont remember right now)

Is Kale stronger than a super saiyan blue in the anime?

Answer (score 1):

Kale is not stronger than Super Saiyan Blue Goku and Vegeta in the anime. This is clearly established during Goku's fight with Kale and Caulifla where Goku was easily holding his own with Kale using Super Saiyan God and easily overwhelmed Caulifla. Kale was more or less relative to SSJG Goku and clearly didn't overpower him. Also, SSJ Kefla was fighting relative to SSJB Goku(Who was exhausted). "A potara fused transformed character". It obviously doesn't make sense for Kale to be stronger when her Potara fused Transformed character, fights relative to SSJB exhausted Goku. Back in the Buu saga, Base Vegito was superior to SSJ3 Goku and Ultimate Gohan.

- We also know for a fact that the Super Saiyan Blue transformation is a lot stronger than the Super Saiyan God transformation based on Goku's initial fight with Jiren and Whis's comments during his fight with Dyspo.
- Goku never fought anyone seriously in the tournament of power until his fight with Jiren. It has been established numerous times in the serious that Goku never fights seriously at the start and always holds back. Even if you look at Goku in the earlier part of the tournament, he could've easily thrown out the fighters of Universe 9 using Super Saiyan  or obliterated them with Super Saiyan Blue which he didn't do.
- Vegeta referred to Kale being a monster on account of her aggressive nature. One power impact from Jiren was strong enough to completely knock out Kale. Goku on the other hand easily survived the power impact even after fighting with Jiren before. Also, even after Kale attacking Goku, he had 0 injuries and sustained no damage.

The power scaling in the manga is different from the anime. For example:

- In the manga, Goku in his mastered SSJB form was able to fight Fused Zamasu and Base Vegito was capable of overwhelming fused Zamasu. While in the anime, SSJB Vegito was more or less relative to Fused Zamasu and only had a slight advantage
- Android 17 is capable of only fighting SSJ3 Goku in the manga but fights with a suppressed SSJB Goku in the anime.

The manga is trying to focus on Universe 6, 7 and 11. Hence, trying to eliminate the other Universes and ended up altering the power levels to fit the story. For example, spoilers indicate Gohan challenges Kefla in the manga and clearly, Gohan is not stronger than Goku. Since the manga cannot focus on every Universe like the anime, the main characters are been given more spotlight and certain subcharacters are being made even weaker.

Answer (score -1):

Not quiet but as the scene we observed in the series goku has a very less amount of stamina left and moreover he doesn't really want to end the fight soon so he is not using his full power